# Как сохранить и систематизировать все отправленные эмодзи на сервере в Discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Пишу бота для дс, который мог бы достать из каждого сообщения на сервере все эмодзи и хотя бы сохранить каждый смайл в какой нибудь файл. Но я новичок и плохо представляю себе это.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        a = str(message.content)
        a = list(a)
        orig_list = a
        new_list = re.findall(r'[^\w\s,.]', orig_list[0])
        print(new_list)
```

Это по какой то причине просто выдает квадратные скобки.